# Process border cells of matrix

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I would like to process every border cell of a *nxn* matrix. For example, for *int array[5][5];* algorithm should process every *x* element, so it has the form

```
   x x x x x 
   x - - - x
   x - - - x
   x - - - x
   x x x x x
```

What's the best way to process this cells? What about if it is a 3-dimensional array? Thanks in advance, and sorry for the matrix representation.

**Edit I** I would like to use only one loop in order to avoid nesting loops or recursion.

Comment: C++ or C? There's a difference you know.

Comment: @Magtheridon96 I would prefer C code since I won't use the std library, but I know both, so it's not a problem.

Comment: Do you want this to work for any NxN matrix, or do you want specific dimensions? (Specific dimensions would simplify the solution)

Comment: @Magtheridon96 I've specified *nxn* matrix in the question. *5x5* matrix was an example.

Comment: I'm stupid then. /works

Answer (score 1):

Imagine touching each element has its cost and you want only touch border elements.

Obviously, it's not a general optimization. But I had a good performance with this, in an image processing. **I mean, it depends, test it in your case and decide.**

In 2D arrays you can make a `ptr` points to the matrix and incrementally progresses.

```
void process(char i)
{
    cout << i;
}

int main()
{
    const int N = 5;
    char mat[N][N] = {
        {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'},
        {'f', '-', '-', '-', 'g'},
        {'h', '-', '-', '-', 'i'},
        {'j', '-', '-', '-', 'k'},
        {'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p'}
    };

    char *ptr = (char*) mat;

    for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; ++i) // Process first row
        process(*ptr++);

    for (int i = 0; i < N - 2; ++i) // Process column borders
    {
        process(*ptr);
        process(*(ptr + 1));
        ptr += N;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= N; ++i)    // Process last row
        process(*ptr++);

    cout << endl;
}
```

Output:

> abcdefghijklmnop

Comment: Thanks. I already thought this way of processing this cells. Is this more efficient than using only a loop and determining components of border cells, as I explained in Tushar's answer?

Answer (score -1):

You basically want to process the cases where `index == 0` and `index == size` for every dimension in your array. Assuming `process()` is your processing function and takes a int argument.

```
void processNXNBorders(int** twoDArray, int dimonesize, int dimtwosize) {
    for (int i = 0; i < dimonesize; i++) {
        if (i == 0 || i == dimonesize-1) {
            // Process entire row
            for (int j = 0; j < dimtwosize; j++) {
                 process(twoDArray[i][j]);
            }
        } else {
            // Only first and last elements in this row.
            process(twoDArray[i][0]);
            process(twoDArray[i][dimtwosize-1]);
        }
    }
}
```

So for a 5x5 array, the call would be:

```
processNXNBorders(arr, 5, 5);
```

Comment: At first 'if' should be i==dimonesize-1 or i<=dimonesize at first 'for', right?. Thanks for the answer, but is there a way to process borders without nested loops?

Comment: @BenWard Yes, my mistake. There is a recursive solution to this problem as well, but recursion and iteration are just two different ways to do the same thing.

Comment: Right, but I would like to determine iteratively the components of the border cells without nested loops nor recursion. For example, a function that returns i,j components given a number from 1 to 4*dim-1, in order to avoid nested loops.