# How to eliminate the border elements in the 2d array using cpp

Tags: c++

[Process border cells of matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589203/process-border-cells-of-matrix)

this program will consider only the border elements. I need to know how to get the exact opposite.

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: Just do the exact opposite... and provide provide [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Dou you want help with writing loops which cover the first line, the last line and the first and last in each of the remaining lines? What exactly is the problem you have whith that seemingly simple goal. Without more explanation and more specific details, your question is either "unclear" or "too broad".

Answer (score 1):

For all the border elements one of these will always apply:

```
(i,j) is in the form of (0,*), (*,0), (N-1, *), (*, N-1)
```

where N is the size of the matrix.

```
int main()
{
    const int N = 5;
    char mat[5][5] = {
        {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'},
        {'f', '-', '-', '-', 'g'},
        {'h', '-', '-', '-', 'i'},
        {'j', '-', '-', '-', 'k'},
        {'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p'}
    };

    for (size_t i=1;i<N-1;i++)
    {
        for(size_t j=1;j<N-1;j++)
        {
            printf("%c",mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can get rid of the if condition by adjusting your for loops as `for (size_t i=1;i<N-1;i++) {...}`. Dito for `j`

Comment: yeah right, thanks

Comment: edited it!! thanks for the suggestion